# dataframe.resample('4T').mean() is yielding an incorrect first result but subsequent results are consistent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

"df.resample('4T').mean()" is yielding it's first result before the fourth value of the dataframe. It continues to accurately find the mean of the next four values, but because the initial value is off I'm not getting the values where I need them in the dataframe.  In fact '7T','8T',and '9T' are all yielding their first results at the wrong position while '3T', '5T', and '10T' are working as expected.

Code:

```
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('stockPrices/closingPrices-mar29b.csv',index_col='date',parse_dates=True)
df['close'] = df['close'].shift(1)
df['4ma'] = df.resample('4T').mean().shift(1)
print(df.tail())
```

csv file I'm working with: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HzKrwcDM233uqlNZI_TdLmewJLIuKM-mKLiRtTlNauc/edit?usp=sharing

Current Result:

```
                        close        4ma
date                                    
2019-03-25 09:34:00  279.1300        NaN
2019-03-25 09:33:00  278.9300        NaN
2019-03-25 09:32:00  278.8500  278.72875
2019-03-25 09:31:00  278.6900        NaN
2019-03-25 09:30:00  278.7675        NaN
```

Desired Result:

```
                        close        4ma
date                                    
2019-03-25 09:34:00  279.1300   278.8094
2019-03-25 09:33:00  278.9300        NaN
2019-03-25 09:32:00  278.8500        NaN
2019-03-25 09:31:00  278.6900        NaN
2019-03-25 09:30:00  278.7675        NaN
```

Attempts to remedy:

1.Used 'loffset'='2T' as follows, but the averages were inaccurate:

```
df['4ma loffset'] = df['close'].resample('4T',loffset='-2T').mean().shift(1)
```

2.Changed the order of the dataframe:

```
df = df.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

3.Eliminated all shifting of columns in code. '5T' put first 5min average in the first minute of the dataframe and was thereafter consistent, but '4T' still yielded its first result before fourth minute.

**Note about the use of 'shift' in my code. I shift my 'close' column in the original dataframe and then I shift the 'ma' column once I create it. The stock data I receive starts at 9:31 and ends at 16:00. The 9:31 price is originally the closing price of the minute 9:30:01-9:31:00. Because I want moving averages right at MM:SS (like a 5 minute moving average at 9:35:00), I have to shift(1) on my original dataframe to put a number in a the empty 9:30:00 index. I also have to shift my 'ma' column, otherwise I get values at the beginning of the time block as follows:

```
2019-03-25 09:34:00  279.1300        NaN
2019-03-25 09:33:00  278.9300        NaN
2019-03-25 09:32:00  278.8500        NaN
2019-03-25 09:31:00  278.6900        NaN
2019-03-25 09:30:00  278.7675  278.87350
```

Comment: I also tried using different csv files with a similar pattern of data and got the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Use any of the following columns to get an accurate resample:

```
df['4ma'] = df.resample('4T', base=2).mean().shift(1)
df['7ma'] = df.resample('7T', base=3).mean().shift(1)
df['8ma'] = df.resample('8T', base=2).mean().shift(1)
df['9ma'] = df.resample('9T', base=1).mean().shift(1)
```

The following GitHub thread suggests using "base=x" to solve this issue in Pandas:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4197

Essentially, when downsampling in Pandas with minute data, Pandas attempts to "infer" different starting points. Changing the base changes where the sampling begins.

I don't understand the logic behind the inferred feature of Pandas, but adjusting the base solves this issue.